# $A(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ in [a,b],let c in (a,b),if $f'$ is continuous at c then A' is continuous at c?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

this is an exercise in Apostol calculus I page 210.
Given a function $f$ such that the integral $A(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ exists for each $x$ in an interval $[a,b]$.Let $c$ be a point in $(a,b)$.Prove that if $f'$ is continuous at $c$.then $A'$ is continuous at $c$.

Attempt:
f' is continuous at c,so there's a interval $c- \delta<x<c+ \delta$ such that $f'(x)$ exists and  $|f'(x)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$, this imply $f$ is continuous in the interval.By the first fundamental theorem of calculus.$A'(x)=f(x)$ in $(c- \delta,c+ \delta)$.because $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$. So does A'.

I feel my statement is quite strange and may have  something wrong.Hope someone could give a clear explaination to me.

Comment: I think it should read like this: "Since $f'(x)$ exists and is continuous at $c$, we know that $f$ is continuous at $c$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that $A'(x) = f(x)$, and since $f$ is continuous at $c$ it follows that $A'$ is also continuous at $c$." Probably not as I have written, but possibly the ideas are in that order.

Comment: @Fantini thanks for the reply.the first fundamental theorem of  calculus didn't imply the  continuity of $A'$ at $c$ by the continuity of $f$ at $c$,it only states $A'(c)=f(c)$ if $f$ is continuous at $c$.So my attempt is  to try to show there's an open interval contain $c$ such that $f$ is continuous in the interval.by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have $A'(x)=f(x)$ in the interval,then $A'(x)$ can inherit the continuity of $f$ at $c$.  No only the statement also I like to know if my attempt is plausible.

Comment: I feel you haven't quite understood the order of my arguments and its implications. First, I asserted that since $f'$ exists and is continuous at $c$, then $f$ is also continuous at $c$. So far $A(x)$ hasn't showed up. Then I used the fundamental theorem of calculus: we know $A'(x) = f(x)$. Regardless of continuity, we know $A'(c) = f(c)$. But we know $f$ is continuous at $c$ by the first argument, therefore $A'$ is continuous at $c$ since $A'(x) = f(x)$ which is continuous at $c$.

Comment: I don't think you need to size up $\varepsilon-\delta$ here. Also, I'm not certain, but I don't think you can say that since $f'$ exists at a point that it exists at a interval. Moreover, with the definition of $A(x)$ we know that $A'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, regardless of continuity.

Comment: @Fantini The original question from apostol is an T/F table-to-fill style.Actually it has another question "$f$ is continuous at $c$" and it implies $A'(x) =f(x)$ and $A(x)$ is continuous at $c$,not $A'(x)$ is continuous at $c$.without the continuity of $f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ but only by the definition of $A(x)$ we can't have $A'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.and this is based on the fundamental theorem of calculus.About the statement I said since $f'$ is continuous at $c$ so there exists an interval,not $f'$ exists at $c$ then it exists an interval.

Comment: I am at loss of what you meant. I think I'm not understanding what is the trouble. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of $\varepsilon-\delta$ arguments.
Currently one can speak of continuity of a derivative in a point if the derivative exists in a neighborhood of the point.
In this case the continuity of $f'$ in $c$ implies the existence of $f'$ in a neighborhood of $c$ and so the continuity of $f$ in the same neighborhood.
Then the fundamental theorem assures that $A'$ exists and is equal to $f$ in a neighborhood of $c$ and so is continuous in $c$.